Dart has problems with CSV files
I have the following CSV file :
$ cat ../SyncedShazams.csv
"artist","title","status","date","longitude","latitude"
"Queen","Fat Bottomed Girls","N/A","2024-04-09T22:03:30.164Z","N/A","N/A"
"W&W & AXMO","Heaven Is a Place On Earth","N/A","2024-04-09T21:59:34.614Z","N/A","N/A"
"Kleks & sanah","Jestem Twoją Bajką","N/A","2024-04-07T05:07:22.333Z","N/A","N/A"
"Oskar Cyms","Nigdy wcześniej","N/A","2024-04-06T04:49:43.106Z","N/A","N/A"
"Heidi Montag","I'll Do It","N/A","2024-04-04T07:23:10.340Z","N/A","N/A"
"vowl. & Sace","2000","N/A","2024-04-04T07:22:53.608Z","N/A","N/A"
"City High","What Would You Do?","N/A","2024-04-03T20:22:52.658Z","N/A","N/A"
"City High","What Would You Do?","N/A","2024-04-03T20:22:32.131Z","N/A","N/A"
"Kleks, IGO, Kaśka Sochacka, Mrozu, Artur Rojek, Brodka, Ralph Kaminski, Bedoes 2115 & Sokół","Całkiem Nowa Bajka","N/A","2024-03-29T23:39:11.413Z","N/A","N/A"

The columns have to be converted as follows:
Queen - Fat Bottomed Girls
Kleks, IGO, Kaśka Sochacka, Mrozu, Artur Rojek, Brodka, Ralph Kaminski, Bedoes 2115 & Sokół - Całkiem Nowa Bajka

However, the current Dart code only prints HELLO out.
$ cat bin/shazam.dart
import 'package:shazam/shazam.dart' as shazam;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() async {
  try {
    final String csvData = await readFile('../SyncedShazams.csv'); 
    final List<List<dynamic>> rows = const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvData);
    print("HELLO");
  
    // Skip the header and process each row
    for (var row in rows.skip(1)) {
      if (row.length > 1) {
        // Artists and song title are expected to be in the first and second columns respectively
        print('${row[0]} - ${row[1]}');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to process CSV: $e');
  }
}

Future<String> readFile(String filePath) async {
  final file = File(filePath);
  try {
    return await file.readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Failed to read the file: $e');
  }
}

Dart output:
$ dart run
Building package executable... 
Built shazam:shazam.
HELLO


What did I miss?

Your code appears to work for me. Are you sure the file name, and file path are correct? Are you sure you have saved the CSV file? Are there any exceptions thrown or error messages displayed?

I updated my question. The path appears correct, and Dart does not complain that the file is missing.

What output do you get if you print(rows); after print('HELLO')?

I added print(rows);  and it printed out the CSV file $ dart run | head HELLO [[artist, title, status, date, longitude, latitude Queen, Fat Bottomed Girls, N/A, 2024-04-09T22:03:30.164Z, N/A, N/A City High, What Would You Do?, N/A, 2024-04-03T20:22:52.658Z, N/A, N/A City High, What Would You Do?, N/A, 2024-04-03T20:22:32.131Z, N/A, N/A. What is wrong with the for loop?

Is this perhaps a line-ending problem?  What line-endings does your .csv file use?

343
$ grep -c $'\r\n' ../SyncedShazams.csv 
343
$ awk 'END { if (sub(/\r$/, "")) print "CR LF"; else print "LF" }'  ../SyncedShazams.csv
LF```

I don't think those grep commands do what you think they do.  I'm not fluent with awk and can't judge the correctness.  Normally I'd suggest just using the file command which usually reports if a file has CRLF line-endings, but AFAICT it doesn't for CSV files.  Perhaps try dos2unix -ih ../SyncedShazams.csv (or just opening the CSV file in VS Code or Sublime Text or whatever).

../SyncedShazams.csv: CSV text``` and ```$ dos2unix -ih ../SyncedShazams.csv
     DOS    UNIX     MAC  BOM       TXTBIN  FILE
       0     343       0  no_bom    text    ../SyncedShazams.csv```

Please find here the whole CSV file.

Seems the row separator should be CR+LF, according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180

After downloading your CSV file, it appears that the issue is indeed line endings as jamesdlin pointed out,
I was using CRLF line endings (\r\n) while your file uses LF line endings (\n).
You have 2 possible solutions here.

Convert the file  to using \r\n line endings.

Update the code to expect \n line endings.
As it turns out the CsvToListConverter() expects \r\n by default, but you can pass in an eol named parameter like so CsvToListConverter(eol: '\n').


